# Trigger post-receive hook without pushing any refs

Tags: git, githooks

Is there any way to trigger the post-receive hook of a git repository without pushing anything?

I'm aware that I can just push an empty commit, which will cause the hook to trigger:

```
git commit --allow-empty -m "push me" && git push
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows, assuming you have access to the server:

```
echo `git log -2 --format=oneline --reverse | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | xargs` master | ./hooks/post-receive
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is.  If you have control of the server, you can log in there and run the post-receive hook manually, but this runs in a different environment from an actual receive operation.  You can simulate the environment more closely by making sure the current directory is in the repository and that `$GIT_DIR` is set to `.`.

(When I ran some central-server side git repos in a previous job, I just had some special test repositories I would push to, to run my hooks in "really receiving data" mode for final testing.)